# Can't get display name annotation to work on scaffolded dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an entity called Contract, and a property in contract as follows:

```
[Display(Name = "Contract Type")]
[Required]
public int ContractTypeId { get; set; }
```

ContractTypeId is a foreign key relating to another entity.

If I scaffold a controller and views for the Contract entity, it generates a dropdown for ContractTypeId (as it should), and populates properly - but it doesn't apply the correct label "Contract Type" instead it still displays ContractTypeId as the label and ignores the data annotation.

This happens in a fresh project as well - anyone any ideas?

Comment: Are you using `Html.LabelFor` to generate the label? If not, what do you use?

Comment: Yep - using the HTML.LabelFor

Comment: Do you have a `ContractType` navigation property too?

Comment: Yes - there is a navigation property.

Comment: Did you try putting the `Display` attribute on there instead?

Comment: It might help if you post the relevant code in your view, and viewmodel (with properties relevant to rendering your dropdown). Currently, there is nothing in your question that looks wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I ran into the same issue and figured out what my error was. Here was the solution in my case if someone else encounters the same issue.

Check your view file, the scaffolding could have automatically added a string for the label. In the example below, the scaffolding added "CustomerId" as the label for the dropdown. If you remove the "CustomerId" field, then it will grab the label you set in the display.

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerId, "CustomerId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("CustomerId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
</div>
```